# Suitescript 1.0 - Get line item units in sales order

Tags: javascript, suitescript

I'm trying to get the units text for a sales order in suitescript 1.0 with nlapiGetLineItemText('item','units',i). This works for other select fields such as 'item', but 'units' always returns an empty string. nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','units',i) returns an integer that seems to correspond to specific unit types, but I'm not sure how it relates or if I can use this to extract the units text.

Here's the code:

```
var lineCount = nlapiGetLineItemCount('item');
var items = [];
var itemObj = {};

var invTypes = ['InvtPart','NonInvtPart','Assembly','Kit'];

for(let i = 1; i <= lineCount; i++) {

    let itemType = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','itemtype',i);

    if(invTypes.indexOf(itemType) != -1) {
        let itemObj = {
            name:nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','description',i),
            qty:nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','quantity',i),
            units:nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','units',i),
            panel_qty:nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','custcol_panelqty',i),
            panel_ft:nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','custcol_feet',i),
            panel_in:nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','custcol_inch',i)
        };
        console.log(itemObj);
        items.push(itemObj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the text from the units type record by loading it:
`nlapiLoadRecord('unitstype', nlapiGetLineItemValue('item','units',i)).getFieldValue('name')` or through a search.

Comment: Hmm that's returning the wrong value. We have Multiple Units of Measure enabled which may be throwing things off. `nlapiGetlineItemValue('item','units',i)` returns the Units Type id, while `nlapiLoadRecord('unitstype',value).getFieldValue('name')` returns the Units of Measure for that id.

Comment: You can see the units under Lists > Accounting > Units of Measure. Which field on the unit record are you trying to get?